# Enterprise custom fields are not rolling up in project center view

Tags: ms-project

I am trying to sum project values by their project types. I created a project view then added some calculated enterprise custom fileds and ms project calculated fields like actual work and baseline work to the view and grouped by their project type.

MS project calculated fields like actual work and baseline work are rolling up by their project type but enterprise custom fileds are not. Formulas and rollups working fine in ms project file but not working in project center view. Is it not supported? Or what should I do to ?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Merve